# How to find a designer if I'm unable to name the style I'm looking for?

Tags: illustration

I'd like to hire a designer that can create custom illustrations just like the examples below. However, I have no idea what this style is called, or how to best find such a designer once I know what it's called.

Notice that the lines aren't fully straight or consistent in their width in several of these illustrations, which gives a hand-drawn organic feel.

I've browsed plenty of sites like Dribbble but have never seen illustrations quite like those. I'm a dev and would need those done for various apps.

Examples of the style I'm looking for:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what a mood board is for. You **show** your prospective designer things you like. They don't all have to have a name.

Comment: Most often, any style is just *described* as you have here. A specific style is rarely "named" unless it's an overused *trend*, in which case it may not be desirable from a marketing standpoint. Even well know styles don't always have a name.. i.e. Keith Haring's style is called "Keith Hering's style".

Comment: Design styles don't necessarily have specific names. You could however just describe them. These are what I would call coloured line icons. They have a distinct linedrawing feel (a black outline), slightly irregular/hand drawn, but are filled with colour. Also if you show your designer what you want, that should help.

Comment: Everything you guys are saying is right, but none of it helps me figure out how/where to find a designer who could do that. That's the question I'm asking

Comment: That's easy. You make a mood board, send it along to potential designers, and ask them "Is this a style you are comfortable with?" Maybe ask a few examples of previous work to make sure they're not bluffing. Contacting three or four should do the trick.

Comment: For styles like this, I'd go with a designer that is also an illustrator

Comment: If you're asking where to hire a designer, that's not what this stack does. A simple internet search will uncover places on the web you can post job openings.

Comment: @PieBie , thank you for the edits and for your advice. Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Consolidating the info in the comments into a single, cohesive answer*:

Most often, any style is just described as you have here. A specific style is rarely "named" unless it's an overused trend, in which case it may not be desirable from a marketing standpoint. Even well known styles don't always have a name. i.e. Keith Haring's style is called "Keith Haring's style".

If you want a designer to design something specific, the best way to go about this is to *show* them what you want. A popular method for this is a [mood board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mood_board). But just a collection of other work you like is also OK, you don't *have* to be professional about it (that's what the designer is for )

Once you're happy with your mood board, send it along with your work request to a few designers in the neighbourhood. (Google is your friend here) You can check their website or portfolio to get a feel of the styles they're comfortable with. If you want to be really sure, ask for a few examples of past work in the same vein.

Comment: Thanks, PieBie. Too new to vote up your answer, but I marked it as "Accepted" 